# Ruby gem jekyll is installed but is not recognized

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

As a premise, i know basically nothing about how ruby and ruby gems work. I just wanted to make a static website on github pages by following this tutorial: [giraffe academy](https://yewtu.be/watch?v=pxua_1vyFck&list=PLLAZ4kZ9dFpOPV5C5Ay0pHaa0RJFhcmcB&index=3&autoplay=1)

I'm on Windows 10, ruby 3.2.2 gem 3.4.10.

After (what i think it is) a successful installation of jekyll, it doesn't seem that windows can find the path to it to use it as a command.

I installed jekyll with

```
`gem install bundler jekyll`
```

And got a positive response, as a matter of fact i checked by

```
`gem which jekyll`
```

and the result is the path to it C:/Users/.../.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll.rb

and with
`gem list`

which returned between the others

```
irb (default: 1.6.2)
jekyll (4.3.2)
jekyll-sass-converter (3.0.0)
jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
json (default: 2.6.3)
kramdown (2.4.0)
```

still when i try to use jekyll as a command i get the following error:

```
    jekyll new githubTestWebsite

   'jekyll' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

i tried multiple times to reinstall it and to browse multiple forums but nothing seems to work.
A thing i noticed is that the jekyll gem is installed under C: while my actual Ruby is installed under G: (which is my other drive) can it be relevant? anyways calling it from either one doesn't work.

Comment: I believe this is a matter of reading the Jekyll documentation for How to install on Windows? I'll leave the link [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was installing jekyll correctly with:

```
`gem install bundler jekyll`
```

but from the wrong command prompt. I was using the standard one (red), instead what i should have done is using the 'start command prompt with ruby' (green) option.

At first i didn't notice it was there since i didn't restart the pc, so there was no option to choose.

[image]